# Bound for the number of neighbors regions

Tags: connectedness, combinatorial-geometry, upper-lower-bounds

Consider the $2^n$ hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ passing through the origin one for each $x ∈ \left \{0, 1\right \}^n$ with normal $(x, 1)$.
These hyperplanes divide $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ into [$2\sum_{k=0}^{n}  \binom{2^n-1}{k}$ connected regions](https://books.google.ru/books?id=qOy4yLBqhFcC&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=The%20maximum%20number%20of%20connected%20regions%20into%20which%20Rd%20can%20be%20partitioned%20by%20N%20hyperplanes%20passing%20through%20the%20origin&source=bl&ots=BfEHr8jens&sig=n2SrOQd0luJyOiIaN2H4TBSp0lQ&hl=ru&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=The%20maximum%20number%20of%20connected%20regions%20into%20which%20Rd%20can%20be%20partitioned%20by%20N%20hyperplanes%20passing%20through%20the%20origin&f=false).

Say regions "neighbors" if they have a common hyperplane.

How many neighboring regions do the selected region have?

I want to prove that the neighbors  $\geq n$.